# The best Python/Django architecture for image heavy web application

Tags: python, django, image-processing, imagekit, photologue

I am building a web application that allows users to upload images to their accounts - similar to flickr and 500px. 
I want to know the best setup for such an application. I'm using Python 3.4 and Django 1.9

I'm currently thinking about the following:

- Heroku
- AWS S3
- Postgres

I'm struggling to find a suitable image processing library. I've looked at ImageKit and Photologue. But I find Photologue to be a little bit heavy for what I want to do.

I'm basically looking for a way to allow users to upload images of a certain size without locking up the Heroku dynos. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use django-photologue, you can define a thumbnail size and specify that the thumbnail should not be generated at upload time - instead, it gets generated the first time the thumbnail is requested for display.

If you have lots of different sized thumbnails for a photo, this trick can help a user upload their photos faster.

Source: I maintain django-photologue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for: [Django-Photologue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/django-photologue/)